# Harry Potter fanfiction homage to "The Great Divorce"

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember reading a non-*Deathly Hallows*-compliant HP fanfiction a while back. I particularly liked at the time, and I'm trying to find it again so that I can re-read it.

*Plot*: the final battle ends with both Harry and Voldemort dying. They wake up as dry skeletons in the afterlife, portrayed as some sort of untamed, pastoral countryside. With nothing better to do, the two wander around, trying to find other people. Living up to his chosen moniker (literally, "flight from death"), Voldemort refuses to accept his death; Harry is more realistic about things. Eventually, they encounter Severus Snape, who has gone nearly catatonic with regret. Both try to get him to come with them (Voldemort pulls rank, Harry tries to appeal to Snape's better nature), and both fail. Eventually, they reach the Valley of the Shadow of Death, where Nagini has been waiting for Voldemort. Deciding that it is better to reign in Hell than serve in Heaven, Voldemort remains there. Harry continues on, and eventually reaches a forest. There he finds a ballroom made of trees (possibly called the "Valley of the Shadow of Life"?), where people take part in the Great Dance and gradually get their flesh back. He encounters Luna Lovegood (who had died at some point prior to the final battle), who invites him to dance with her. Harry declines, saying that he feels obligated to save Snape.

The whole thing is stylistically very similar to *The Great Divorce*, by C.S. Lewis. The author mentions in a postscript that he wrote it as an homage to Lewis's novel (and MacDonald's *Lilith*? I don't remember if that was mentioned in the fiction's postscript or the introduction to *The Great Divorce*, which I re-read shortly afterward).

I believe I read it on FanFiction.net; however, I am not confident in this.